# Disable minor mode in all open buffers

Tags: buffers, minor-mode

Often I have many buffers open and, for whatever reason, I no longer wish to use a particular minor mode with them. Is there currently a built-in way to disable a particular minor mode for all open buffers, or does this require writing a custom elisp function?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This does require a custom elisp function unless the minor mode has a `(global-*-mode)` function attached to it.

Luckily, it is a pretty simple function:

```
(defun global-disable-mode (mode-fn)
  "Disable `MODE-FN' in ALL buffers."
  (interactive "a")
  (dolist (buffer (buffer-list))
    (with-current-buffer buffer
      (funcall mode-fn -1))))
```

To use (for example, on `projectile-mode`):

```
(global-disable-mode 'projectile-mode)
```

Or call it interactively:

```
M-x global-disable-mode RET projectile-mode
```

Comment: Seems to work! And nicely written to boot. Thank you very much. =)

Comment: alternatively, if you only need this one time, you can just copy Eval the body of the function: `M-S-; (dolist ....)` and replace `mode-fn` with 'projectile-mode in this case.